# How to switch PR to other branch?

Tags: github

I have a github PR with comments to merge a branch polina:X to somerepo:master. I recreated the branch. I want to update the PR to merge polina:Y to somerepo:master.

How can I do this?

It is different from what is explained [here](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/changing-the-base-branch-of-a-pull-request), because I want to change `from` branch, not `to` branch.